# existing gulp task errors with "Task 'dev' is not in your gulpfile" when run as npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

In a nutshell: I have a task in my gulpfile. It runs fine when I `gulp mytask`. But when I try to use it as npm's `start` script, I get an error.

Setup:

```js
//gulpfile.js (gulp 4)

var dev = gulp.series(a,series,of,tasks);
gulp.task('dev', dev);
```

`gulp dev` behaves as expected: `a` runs, then `series`, etc.

But when I add `gulp dev` as my `npm start` script in package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gulp dev"
  }
}
```

`npm start` errors with

```
npm start

> my-project@1.0.0 start correct/path/to/project
> gulp dev

Using gulpfile correct/path/to/gulpfile.js
Task 'dev' is not in your gulpfile
Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Content of your package.json file?

Comment: Nothing relevant I don't think - just the essentials. name, version, description, main, repository, author, license, private, and dependencies (all dependencies are for my gulp tasks)

Comment: And gulp v4 too?

Comment: Yep, gulp 4 is one of the dependencies. Everything in my gulpfile is working as expected when run directly by gulp (e.g. `gulp dev`)

Comment: Could it be you have gulp installed globally and that's the one being used?

Answer (score 0):

I was on Gulp v4.0.0-alpha.1. Not sure how that happened, but it doesn't matter :) With Gulp v4.0.0 it works as expected.